# Alternative to Buffer.BlockCopy for arrays of reference types

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Is there a safe alternative to "**Buffer.BlockCopy**" for arrays of reference types?

**Edit**:

1. My purpose is to move data between arrays of different ranks, e.g. from Object[] to Object[,] without iterating through arrays.
2. **Buffer.BlockCopy** works with primitive types only.
3. **Array.Copy** works with arrays of the same rank.

Comment: What kind of safety are you looking for?

Comment: Something that can be used in production...

Comment: Do you want the array not to be modified while performing the copying?

Comment: Actually, I need to copy the same data between arrays of different ranks.

Comment: Dmitry: Buffer.BlockCopy works with structs (value types) only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IL has the notion of managed pointers.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8901/An-overview-of-interior-pointers-in-C-CLI) They are tracked by the GC. The object is not pinned.

I believe this copy can be pulled off safely in C++/CLI (or, in IL if you care to use Reflection Emit).

You'd need to define a function like this:

```
void Copy(int itemCount, ref object firstItemArray0, ref object firstItemArray1);
```

And call it like this:

```
object[] array0 = new object[11 * 12];
object[,] array1 = new object[11, 12];

Copy(11 * 12, ref array[0], ref array1[0]);
```

This call submits managed pointers to `Copy`. `Copy` now has a managed pointer to the first element of the arrays to copy between.

`Copy` cannot be expressed in C# because you can't perform pointer arithmetic on managed pointers in C#. In fact, a `ref` does not look like a pointer at all.

The C++/CLI implementation of `Copy` would look something like this:

```
void Copy(
    int itemCount,
    interior_ptr<object^> firstItemArray0,
    interior_ptr<object^> firstItemArray1) {
 for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
  firstItemArray1[i] = firstItemArray0[i];
 }
}
```

Just a sketch. If you don't like having a C++/CLI project, disassemble the IL and generate it using Reflection Emit.

And just to make the point: This is GC friendly and unverifiable but safe. I see no reason why this couldn't go into production.

Now, why not just use a `for` loop? Multi-dimensional arrays are slow with the current JIT. They have bounds checks and index calculations in them. This avoid all of that.

Comment: Thank's usr! Is your method preferable to the next example http://codepaste.net/dy91dj (copying bytes between arrays)

Comment: @user876301 This method in the pastebin does not work for managed references. The GC can relocate objects and rewrite pointers to them at any time. Using managed pointer, like in my answer, ensures that the GC can update those pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx) or just a `for` loop. The perf difference between the mechanism underlying `Buffer.BlockCopy` and these methods will be negligible except for things like moving image data around at 30 FPS. Don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: Sure. However, BlockCopy is capable of moving data between arrays of different ranks (and unfortunately I need this option)

Comment: There's no way in the CLR to do this safely, since arrays of different ranks are treated as different types. Buffer.BlockCopy isn't really safe (it treats the data as bytes, not as types), and therefore gets around this. You'll have to use a for loop.